# How can i display all the data based on different questions in SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I loop through all the condition even though the first condition is met? For example:

```sql
CASE WHEN first_condition is NOT NULL
          THEN ppp."WEIGHT"
     WHEN second_condition IS NOT NULL
          THEN ppp."WEIGHT"
```

The result will be:

```
first_condition  | weight 
second_condition | weight
```

Comment: If you use pseudo code please still format it as you can see in the edited post.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assists you: [mcve].

Comment: Where do those "conditions" come from? Are those columns in the table? If yes, what data type?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You must have diferrent column for each condition:

```
CASE 
  WHEN first_condition is NOT NULL THEN ppp."WEIGHT"
  ELSE NULL 
  END AS Condition1
CASE 
  WHEN second_condition IS NOT NULL THEN ppp."WEIGHT"
  ELSE NULL 
  END AS Condition2
```